# prevendDefault not working on iPhone

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone

I have some buttons on my web. When I click them a text appears. This works on computer version of the web, on Android, but NOT on iPhone (it takes me to the top of the web).

This is the code i'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(event) {
    $('#btn-servicios-1').click(mostrarServicios1);
    $('#cerrar-servicios-1').click(cerrarServicios1);
    $('#btn-servicios-2').click(mostrarServicios2);
    $('#cerrar-servicios-2').click(cerrarServicios2);
    $('#btn-servicios-3').click(mostrarServicios3);
    $('#cerrar-servicios-3').click(cerrarServicios3);
    $('#btn-servicios-4').click(mostrarServicios4);
    $('#cerrar-servicios-4').click(cerrarServicios4);
  });

  function cerrarServicios1(event) {
    /*event.preventDefault();*/
    $("#contenido-servicios-1").hide();
    return false;
  }

  function mostrarServicios1(event) {
    /*event.preventDefault();*/
    $("#contenido-servicios-1").css("display", "-webkit-box");
    $("#contenido-servicios-1").css("display", "-ms-flexbox");
    $("#contenido-servicios-1").css("display", "-webkit-flex");
    $("#contenido-servicios-1").css("display", "flex");
    $("#contenido-servicios-1").css("flex-wrap", "wrap");
    return false;
  }

  function cerrarServicios2(event) {
    /*event.preventDefault();*/
    $("#contenido-servicios-2").hide();
    return false;
  }

  function mostrarServicios2(event) {
    /*event.preventDefault();*/
    $("#contenido-servicios-2").css("display", "-webkit-box");
    $("#contenido-servicios-2").css("display", "-ms-flexbox");
    $("#contenido-servicios-2").css("display", "-webkit-flex");
    $("#contenido-servicios-2").css("display", "flex");
    $("#contenido-servicios-2").css("flex-wrap", "wrap");
    return false;
  }

  function cerrarServicios3(event) {
    /*event.preventDefault();*/
    $("#contenido-servicios-3").hide();
    return false;
  }

  function mostrarServicios3(event) {
    /*event.preventDefault();*/
    $("#contenido-servicios-3").css("display", "-webkit-box");
    $("#contenido-servicios-3").css("display", "-ms-flexbox");
    $("#contenido-servicios-3").css("display", "-webkit-flex");
    $("#contenido-servicios-3").css("display", "flex");
    $("#contenido-servicios-3").css("flex-wrap", "wrap");
    return false;
  }

  function cerrarServicios4(event) {
    /*event.preventDefault();*/
    $("#contenido-servicios-4").hide();
    return false;
  }

  function mostrarServicios4(event) {
    /*event.preventDefault();*/
    $("#contenido-servicios-4").css("display", "-webkit-box");
    $("#contenido-servicios-4").css("display", "-ms-flexbox");
    $("#contenido-servicios-4").css("display", "-webkit-flex");
    $("#contenido-servicios-4").css("display", "flex");
    $("#contenido-servicios-4").css("flex-wrap", "wrap");
    return false;
  }

</script>
```

This are the buttons (I post one, all have same code):

```
<li style="">
    <a id="btn-servicios-1" href="#">
        <span style="display: block;" class="animated flipInY">Unifamiliar</span>
    </a>

    <div id="contenido-servicios-1" class="contenido-servicios text-center">
        Some text.
        <div id="cerrar-servicios-1" class="boton-cerrar-servicios">X</div>
                    </div>

                  </li>
```

I tested it with 'preventDefault' and with 'return: false;', but dont works.

PD: in iPhone, if you load the web in 'desktop mode', works fine (but not in "normal" mode).

Sorry for my english.

Comment: retry `event.stopPropagation()`

Comment: in some cases, both should be used: `event.stopPropagation();` with `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: @BenG I tested it but this not fix the problem :(

Kaddath I tried putting both, but did not solve the error.

Comment: You're using the global `event` instead of the `event` that is actually triggered by the click. I think changing your click functions like this should work: `$('#btn-servicios-1').click(function(e) { mostrarServicios1(e); });`

Comment: @vi5ion Why do you think he's using the global `event`? He has `event` in the argument list, so it's the event that jQuery passes to the handler.

Comment: @Kaddath `return false;` should do both `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()`. So he doesn't need to write either of these when using jQuery and `return false;`.

Comment: Can you show your HTML? Buttons don't have any default action, so there's nothing to prevent.

Comment: @Barmar you're right, i never use this feature because jQuery's return false behaviours different than vanilla's one (which doesn't stop propagation). Never remember who is who

Comment: `<a>` is an anchor (link), not a button.

Comment: @Barmar it's true, sorry for dont use the correct words. Anyway I think it must work

Comment: Can you change the HTML? `href="javascript:void(0)"` should prevent any jumping.

Comment: @vi5ion I tried that you say but still not working :(

Comment: @Barmar added javascript:void(0) in href but still not working

Comment: Then the problem isn't related to the default action of the links, it's something else.

Comment: @Barmar any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "top of the web"? It goes to the home page?

Comment: What if you remove the `href` attribute entirely?

Comment: I tried changing 'click' for 'mousedown' like this: $('#btn-servicios-1').mousedown(function(event) { mostrarServicios1(event);});.

Now link dont take me to the top of tha page, but the text still not appears.

Comment: @Barmar i means scroll top in the same html page.

Comment: There must be some other event handler doing this. That's not what `href="#"` or `href="javascript:void(0)` does. There's no way to tell why it may be happening from the code you've posted.

Comment: @Barmar i have bootstrap modals too in the web, but i dont know if is a problem or no. (Is not a problem on pc and android)